# Load CSS conditional on custom field is present

Tags: functions, conditional-tags

In my `functions.php` I would like to enqueue a CSS file conditional on whether a custom field exists on the page or custom post type. How should I go about this?

```
  function flatsome_scripts() 
    {
    wp_enqueue_style( 'flatsome-icons', get_template_directory_uri() .'/flatme/css/fonts.css', array(), '2.1', 'all' );
        }

    add_action( 'wp_enqueue_scripts', 'flatsome_scripts' );
```

Note that I don't want an answer which is part of the loop. The code should reside in `functions.php`

Comment: Is this on a single page or post?

Comment: no, this is for all my future pages and custom post types.

Comment: i will be manually adding this custom field on the new pages and custom post types.

Answer (score 0):

Ok, I have created my own function to check for True/False condition. This seems to work. What do you think?

```
function is_this_afield() {
global $wp_query;
$postid = $wp_query->post->ID;  
if (get_post_meta($postid, 'flatme', true)) {
return true;
} elseif(is_page_template('template-flat.php')) {
return true;
}else {
return false;
} 
wp_reset_postdata(); 
}

function flatsome_scripts() 
{
if(is_this_afield()) {
wp_enqueue_style( 'flatsome-icons', get_template_directory_uri() .'/flatme/css/fonts.css', array(), '2.1', 'all' );
}
}

add_action( 'wp_enqueue_scripts', 'flatsome_scripts' );
```

Comment: How about using `wp_reset_postdata();` rather than `wp_reset_query();`  which should only be called after query_posts() http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/query_posts#Caveats

Comment: I must say I am not familiar with wp_reset_postdata(); - other people have been using wp_reset_query(); in this context.. should i try your suggestion?

Comment: Yep, Try wp_reset_postdata(); and test for queries

Comment: ok, I have tested my code and it doesn't work on Pages... any ideas why?

Comment: ok, the final code I have posted above works on both pages and custom post types. I will research Brad's suggestion but in the meantime if anyone can elaborate on why his proposed answer is better than this, please do so.

Answer (score 0):

Try the [`custom field parameters for WP_Query`](http://codex.wordpress.org/Class_Reference/WP_Query#Custom_Field_Parameters)

```
$cf_query = new WP_Query( array (
    'order' => 'DESC',
    'meta_query' => array(
        array( 'key' = > '_flatme_key')
    )
));
```

Assumes _flatme_key is your custom field key

Or [`WP_Meta_Query`](http://codex.wordpress.org/Class_Reference/WP_Meta_Query#Usage)

Comment: Brad could you please post the full code for  the function.. I am really confused here - I am not as an expert as I sound ! many thanks in advance :)

Comment: Please research the links. Could take some time to write into a working function and test. Some work is required on your behalf.